Can anyone explain these hand signals in Black Hawk Down?
In a memorable scene from Black Hawk Down (2001), a Delta Force operator uses hand signals to silently tell his team his plan for destroying an enemy gun emplacement. Here is the scene in question:



Can anyone decipher his hand signals? The broad meaning is fairly clear from what happens immediately afterward, but what do the hand signals actually mean?

Screenplay not much help; "A RUMBLE - and Hoot motions with hand signals. They creep forward down the block, guns raised, NODs over their eyes. They fire again -- and commandeer an RPG gun.

They're not signals that I was taught - but I'm British and not a Delta or a Ranger. They also don't seem to match anything I can find searching the internet. I can hazard a guess in what each signal means, though.

regarding site tags, would that be considered "dialogue"?

Apart from the obvious signals where he points to himself and to the other soldier, they don't really appear to be regular hand signals - at least not that I've ever learnt , and not in any training guide I can find on the internet.
I can try and decipher from the context, though:
Hoot (Bana) points at himself then at the technical with the recoilless rifle mount and finally, just below frame, crosses his arms.
Crossing your arms could be a signal that there is an obstruction (although this is already obvious to Hoot's companions as they've already halted in cover) - I think the sharp tugging/pulling motion he makes with his hand as he crosses his arms indicates his intent to strangle or otherwise silently deal with the militia manning the rifle.
After that Hoot points at his companion, makes a hand motion that looks like a quacking duck, and then points at the target. The duck motion is the hardest to figure out. My best guess is that he is telling the other guy to covertly approach the technical. I would have used a low straight sweeping motion instead.
